# editText getting focus when opening the extra Option list and i also want to know how to clear focus when KeyBoard get down like in Google Keep app

Tags: android, android-edittext

[this is my arrow Pressed State View.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjaGk.png)
[this is my normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG192.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:hint="Title"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <EditText
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Enter Text Here"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/symbolId"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:scaleX=".75"
                    android:scaleY=".75"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Symbol"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/extraOptions"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:scaleX="1.25"
                        android:scaleY="1.25"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_black_24dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:scaleX="1.25"
                        android:scaleY="1.25"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_voice_black_24dp"/>
                    <ImageView
                        android:scaleX="1.25"
                        android:scaleY="1.25"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp"/>
           </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <TextView
                   android:textSize="16sp"
                   android:textColor="@color/gray"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:text="last edited "
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="2"/>
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/expandableArrowId"
                   android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:paddingTop="10dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                   android:paddingStart="25dp"
                   android:paddingEnd="25dp"
                   android:scaleX=".6"
                   android:scaleY=".7"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight=".5"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

When I click on arrow textView, then my editText get focus but I want to expand the extra option list, not to focus editText and it does not lose focus by itself, even when I click on any textView in the extra Option list. I want to have editText just like Google Keep editText and secondly I want to ask how can I make sure that my arrow textView will be clearly clickable. I have check many stackOverFlow articles for editText to lose focus when keyboard is down but didn't get anything effective.

Comment: i am understand your question pl provide any image that you want to show.

Comment: Use correct case shift. Your text is unreadable!

Comment: @buhtz can u tell me which part of code is unreadable

Comment: Not the code. The Text. Sentences starting with upper case letter